# How to insert data into Avro Union/Map type

Tags: java, avro

Hi I'm trying to fill my record based on Avro schema using GenericRecord. But all the time when I'm trying to parse it by:

```
public static boolean validateJson(String json, Schema schema) throws Exception {
        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes());
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);

        try {
            DatumReader reader = new GenericDatumReader(schema);
            Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, din);
            reader.read(null, decoder);
            return true;
        } catch (AvroTypeException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I'm getting "not a Union type."

```
schema.avsc
"type": "record",
    "namespace": "com.acme",
    "name": "Test",
    "fields": [
        { "name": "Country", "type": "string" },
        { "name": "eventContextMetadata", "type": ["null", {"type": "map", "values": "string" }]}
        
        ]
}
```

Do someone know how to put this:

```
 { "name": "eventContextMetadata", "type": ["null", {"type": "map", "values": "string" }]}
```

into Record:

avroRecord.put("eventContextMetadata", ??????);  or difernd method.

and how to create a Map and Union?

Comment: You need a nullable map. All map objects are nullable. Try `hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(); record.put("eventContextMetadata", hashMap)`

Comment: Otherwise, AVSC files aren't records, so it's unclear what you're trying to do